# In C# using namespace System declaration can be omitted?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is an example code I got from aspnetwebstack

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/MvcForm.cs

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Web.Mvc.Properties;

namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public class MvcForm : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ViewContext _viewContext;
        private bool _disposed;

        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA1801:ReviewUnusedParameters", MessageId = "httpResponse", Justification = "This method existed in MVC 1.0 and has been deprecated.")]
        [Obsolete("This constructor is obsolete, because its functionality has been moved to MvcForm(ViewContext) now.", true /* error */)]
        public MvcForm(HttpResponseBase httpResponse)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.MvcForm_ConstructorObsolete);
        }

        public MvcForm(ViewContext viewContext)
        {
            if (viewContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("viewContext");
            }

            _viewContext = viewContext;

            // push the new FormContext
            _viewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
        }
```

IDisposable is defined in namespace System.  In order to use it, has to declare the namespace System like this,

```
Using System
```

But in this example, it doesn't declare that.

**My question is**

Is there a place to include a namespace by default without declaration in C# ?

Comment: Perhaps the author omitted it for brevity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`using System;` isn't required in this case because the code is already located in the `System` namespace (see the `namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html` line).

To answer your question, no there is no way to include a namespace without declaration in C# other than already being in that namespace.

Comment: +1. Is it all right to not include `using.System` if it's classes directly from there aren't being used (like `Console.WriteLine()`, for example)?

Comment: @pcnThird It's perfectly legal to omit `using System;`, but usually you'll end up using a class declared in that namespace and that's why it's included almost all the time.